# Any alternative for eval()?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a calculation function for my Dialogflow app.
I read about using eval() and it can be harmful. Is there an alternative method for my functions?

Example :

```
var number = 4
var number1 = 9
var opreator = '+'

console.log(eval(number +opreator+ number1));
```

---

My code:

```
function Calculation(agent){

  var number = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.number;
  var number1 = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.number1;
  var opreator = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.calculation;

  var result = (eval(number+opreator+number1));

  agent.add(result);

}
```

Comment: What are the potential values of `operator`? Can you map each one to a function, like `var operators = { '+': function (a, b) { return a + b; } };` with `operators[operator](number, number1)`?

Comment: As with almost all eval, *yes*, there is a huge problem with the code you describe. **Huge**.

A malicious user could take advantage of translating the request query into code to execute any JavaScript on an unsuspecting person who clicks their link to your site.

Comment: I am assuming you have the list of operators, go with a switch-case instead of eval

Comment: google "predicate engine" prepare to go down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your constraints, you might consider an object that maps operators to operations.

```js
var operations = {
  '+': (a,b) => a+b,
  '-': (a,b) => a-b,
  '*': (a,b) => a*b,
  '/': (a,b) => a/b
}

var number1 = 4;
var number2 = 9;
var operator = '+';
var operation = operations[operator];

console.log( operation(number1,number2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) package. You can use `math.eval()` the same way you are trying to use `eval()` above.

```
var number = 4
var number1 = 9
var operator = '+'

console.log(math.eval(number + operator + number1)); // 13
console.log(typeof math.eval(number + operator + number1)); // "number"
```

The downside is that you have to download the whole package, which is 136 kB when minified and gzipped. Note that they also have a public API for the same use, but that comes with its own pros and cons.